# How to send a local photo with telegram HTTP API in python?

Tags: python, api, http, bots, telegram

so i got this class :

```
import os #for getting the directory location


class telegramBot(object):
    def __init__(self, token = telegram_token, chat_id = telegram_chat_id):
        self.token = token
        self.chat_id = chat_id
        self.base_url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/".format(token)
```

which contains many methods like sendMessage, replyToMessage and etc..

I want to create a method that sends an image from a LOCAL LIBRARY
to my telegram channel trough my Bot.

**I am looking for something that will look like this:**

```
     def sendImage(self, chat_id, image_path, message)
         url = self.base_url + "sendPhoto?chat_id={}&image_path={}&text={}".format(chat_id, image_path, message)
         response = requests.post(url)
         return response
```

But nothing is working and i can't find answers on the web or at the telegram API page
Does anyone made it or know how to do it correctly? is there any better way to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files), it explains a lot on sending files via **Telegram Bot API**.

In Python, you can use this to upload and send a photo to a specific chat:

```py
import requests

token = "your bot token"
chat_id = 1234567  # chat id
file = "photo.jpg"

url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendPhoto"
files = {}
files["photo"] = open(file, "rb")
requests.get(url, params={"chat_id": chat_id}, files=files)
```

> My personal advice: learn and use a [library](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples#python), don't reinvent the wheel.